# HTML/XML special characters cause row breaks reaing csv file

Tags: python, html, csv, encoding

I'm trying read a semicolon delimited CSV file into python. There is a column which contains some XML code, and in some rows, these codes contain special entities such as `&lt;` for `<` and so on. Those semicolons in cause wrong row breaks, resulting in inconsistent number of columns for certain rows. Is there a way to avoid that without replacing every problematic character?

Here is an example of such rows (I've shortened it for matter of visibility):

```
20160210-12:45:43:047;C2ALLIANCE.EAM.EVENT.EAMEVENTREPORT.DPROB14;<?xml version="1.0"?><FAP:Message><eam:Data id="LOTTYPE">R&amp;D</eam:Data></FAP:Message>;EVENT;DPROB14;
```

There are actually 5 columns, while the semicolon in `&amp;` causes an extra break, so my code gets wrong number of columns.

I need certain columns and I use numpy:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('csvfile.csv', delimiter=";", dtype='str',usecols=(0, 1, 3), skip_header=1)
```

If the offending semicolon was between quotation marks, it would be possible to ignore it using pandas; but here, it's completely taken for a delimiter (I'm not the author of the data).

Comment: You need to post a sample of the file you are trying to parse for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: adding to @MichaelRobellard you should post your python code, to show, what you have tried. Anyway, do you know, there is a python module for CSV Files? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I updated the post with an example of the data and my code.

Comment: Your input file is formatted incorrectly. The XML text should be quoted or escaped. Are you the author of that file? Can you change how the file is produced?

Comment: No, I'm not the author of the file.